# Select photos and videos option is not working in android 14

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-permissions, android-14

Android 14 storage permission return denied once i select "Select photos and videos " option. It works fine when "Allow All" is selected . I'm using jetpack compose and kotlin. I get the permission mentioned below,

READ_MEDIA_IMAGES, READ_MEDIA_VIDEO, READ_MEDIA_VISUAL_USER_SELECTED

I want to upload the file from the local store to the server, but I'm unable to do in Android 14. When clicking select phots and videos option.

Comment: you may need to add codes of what you tried to your question